# iphone NSDate with NSDateFormatter Problem

Tags: iphone, format, nsdate

All i am trying to do, is to get an NSString with the value of the current date ( NOW )

with this format:

> 7/14/10 8:20 PM

Exactly like the native mail app of the iPhone.

i am using the following code to do it:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
 [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

but the still the result is:

> Wednesday, July 14, 2010

Does anyone have any idea of how to get this to just WORK ??

Appreciate your answers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setDateStyle:` overrides the custom format string set with `setDateFormat:`.

Answer (score 3):

Besides that you should call `-setDateStyle:` first as per Nikolai answer, your formatting string doesn't match your example, which would be produced by e.g. the following:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy h:mm a"];
```

See the [Unicode date format patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more details.

Comment: Whats really interesting is the format string is kind of useless
because no matter what you set the format string to be, i keep getting this format:

Wednesday, July 14, 2010

why, I DON'T Know

PS: i tried yours

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's [Date Formatting](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) docs.

I haven't tested it, but try

```
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/yy"];
```

Comment: Not working too
i keep getting this:

Wednesday, July 14, 2010